# subtract two values using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<?php $j=1; ?> 
                               <table class="table">
                                  <thead>
                                     <tr>
                                         <th>Sl No</th>
                                        <th>Item</th>
                                        <th>Current Quantity</th>
                                        <th>Procuring Quantity</th>
                                        <th>Updated Quantity</th>
                                     </tr>
                                  </thead>
        <?php
        $res=$_POST['supply'];
        $result=explode("&",$res);
    for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++){ ?>

                                  <tbody>
                                     <tr class="info">
                                         <?php 
                                         $name=$result[$i];
                                              $query=mysql_query("select * from item where item_name='$name'");
                                              $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);

                                         ?>
                                         <td><?php echo $j;?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]"  id="contact_name" required="required" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $result[$i]; ?>" readonly></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="current[]" required="required" class="form-control" value="<?php echo  $row['item_qua'];?>"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="procuring[]"  id="procuring" required="required" class="form-control"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="updated[]"  id="updated" required="required" class="form-control"></td>
                                     </tr>

    <?php $j++; } ?>
         </tbody>
                               </table>
```

I want to subtract Procuring Quantity by Current Quantity.I want result in Updated Quantity. (Current Quantity - Procuring Quantity= Updated Quantity).

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem? What have you done so far to solve it?

Comment: Thanks for posting your code but please format/tidy it up properly and isolate your issue and what you have tried yourself

Comment: Current Quantity - Procuring Quantity= Updated Quantity.. I want to subtract Procuring Quantity by Current Quantity. I want result in Updated Quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : Read current qunatity from previous input and get procuring qunatity from current input. do substraction and add to updated quantity.

**NOTE** - You have put `id` for current, procuring and updated quantity and after finishing loop your html will have duplicate `id`. Please remove that part or assign logic to make unique `id`.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
 // bind change event to procuring quantity
 $('input[name="procuring[]"]').change(function(){
  var $parentTR = $(this).closest('.info');
  // read value for current quantity.
  var current = $parentTR.find('input[name="current[]"]').val();

  // read value for procuring quantity.
  var procuring = $(this).val();

  // do substraction and set value in 5th column for updated quantity.
  var updated = parseFloat(current) - parseFloat(procuring);
  $parentTR.find('input[name="updated[]"]').val(updated );
 });
});

</script>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/srg826dd/19/)**

Comment: I want to display result on change Procuring Quantity.

Comment: please check updated answer and remove duplicate id for input or make then unique

Comment: This is full code ..just include this in your html under `<script></script>` tag. and don't forget to include jquery library in your html.

Comment: where i have to call function means ex onchange="myFunction()"

Comment: you don't need to call onchange, this code will do. Have you used jquery before?

Comment: Copy whole code as it is and put it inside `<head></head>` tag in your jsp. It will work. `jquery.min.js` file is jquery library and will get include from google site autmatically provided that you are connected to internet.

Comment: Its displaying NAN not a number

Comment: Please check updated answer and i have given demo link.

Comment: Thanks .. I am having one more query .. Number of rows depends upon the post values .. if i removed for loop i m getting op. but for loop is also imp.. number of rows changes depends upon post value.

Comment: you can use same script I have provided with or without loop, just follow that you have input name like `name="current[]`, `name="procuring[]`  and `name="updated[]"` in place and in same sequence as you are using currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting the value of the input box by .val() and also give id to current[] , i am giving the id as current. Use the code below to do this

```
 <td><input type="text" name="name[]"  id="contact_name" required="required" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $result[$i]; ?>" readonly></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="current[]" id="current" required="required" class="form-control" value="<?php echo  $row['item_qua'];?>"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="procuring[]" id="procuring" required="required" class="form-control"></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" name="updated[]"  id="updated" required="required" class="form-control"></td>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").keyup(function(){
var current = $("#current").val();
var procuring = $("#procuring").val();
$("#updated").val(current - procuring);
});
});
</script>
```

I hope this helps you